# How to Convert Json Result to Object in c# mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to convert this response to object so that i can use access them using object in c# mvc application.

Following is the code i did:

```
 var response = await client.GetAsync("ApiTest?Amount=" + Amount.ToString() + "&WalletAddress=" + WalletAddress.ToString() + "&TokenCode=" + TokenType.ToString());




                                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                        {

                          result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                          var test1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result));

                                           result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                           var obj =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                                            return Json(new { Message = "Your Transaction Has Been Completed Successfully!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                                        }
```

Following is the Json response but its in string format:

> {"Error":"Transaction amount must be greater than
>   0","Result":null,"IsSuccess":false,"HttpResponse":{"Headers":[{"Key":"X-Frame-Options","Value":["sameorigin"]},{"Key":"Strict-Transport-Security","Value":["max-age=31536000"]},{"Key":"Pragma","Value":["no-cache"]},{"Key":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Value":["*"]},{"Key":"Keep-Alive","Value":["timeout=5, max=100"]},{"Key":"Connection","Value":["Keep-Alive"]},{"Key":"Cache-Control","Value":["no-store,
>   must-revalidate, no-cache, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0"]},{"Key":"Date","Value":["Wed, 28 Feb 2018 09:43:57
>   GMT"]},{"Key":"Set-Cookie","Value":["PHPSESSID=3vbjmnpea9i9n871a8knc3s89q7lufpn;
>   path=/; secure;
>   HttpOnly","visid_incap_992349=On7CIEXMQBq9AtX5/PvHQtp5lloAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACXLL2Z399YXaT6IXztsol+;
>   expires=Wed, 27 Feb 2019 14:49:04 GMT; path=/;
>   Domain=.coinpayments.net","incap_ses_478_992349=pCsbJzCRvCFLbgPwODOiBtx5lloAAAAAR8gvl6uEmcAX0kCi3b/2Ig==;
>   path=/;
>   Domain=.coinpayments.net"]},{"Key":"Server","Value":["Apache"]},{"Key":"X-Iinfo","Value":["5-23697956-23698018
>   NNNN CT(1461 273 0) RT(1519811034346 506) q(0 0 17 1) r(18 19)
>   U6"]},{"Key":"X-CDN","Value":["Incapsula"]}],"ContentBody":"{\"error\":\"Transaction
>   amount must be greater than
>   0\",\"result\":[]}","StatusCode":200,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true,"RequestUri":"https://www.coinpayments.net/api.php","RequestBody":"cmd=create_transaction\u0026amount=0\u0026currency1=USD\u0026currency2=LTCT\u0026buyer_email=3Pt5ebwZsMWV2ij1bnFv1yJYk2155PGzGx\u0026version=1\u0026key=c84f65f198e77895f3edc08e7654379785f1057c7c0c6115bee69ed68371d558"}}

any help would be highly appreciated>
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? You've tagged json.net so I guess you know about that library. Have you studied the documentation to find out how to deserialise JSON?

Comment: i tried this: var response = await client.GetAsync("ApiTest?Amount=" + Amount.ToString() + "&WalletAddress=" + WalletAddress.ToString() + "&TokenCode=" + TokenType.ToString());result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                                            var test1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

Comment: And what was the result of that? P.S. You should paste your code into the question where it's readable, not in the comments - thanks

Comment: i am getting result of the api call in response variable and then tries to deserialize but i gives me the json string not in object form

Comment: `test1` should be a `dynamic` object. So it should have properties. e.g. `test1.Error` should contain "Transaction amount must be greater than 0"

Comment: yes exactly @ADyson thats what i am expecting but its not behaving like so

Comment: Assuming `result` is a string containing the above JSON then you should have no problem - see working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tvod7E

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can utilize Visual Studio's Paste Special feature:

Copy JSON and Paste Special:

[image]

You will get following classes:

```
public class JsonResponse
{
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public Httpresponse HttpResponse { get; set; }
}

public class Httpresponse
{
    public Header[] Headers { get; set; }
    public string ContentBody { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccessStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string RequestUri { get; set; }
    public string RequestBody { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now simply utilize Newtonsoft to deserialize:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(json);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @NainaBlue Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
var jso = JObject.Parse(content);
string value = jso["propertyname"].Value<string>();
```